# Content sorted by machine name not title

Tags: 8, nodes

I've drupal 8 configured on my server then I created content types. Now When I click Add Content on content page all the content types are sorted by machine name and not by their title.

For e.g I've following content types

Alert

Article

Basic Page

Category Landing Page

TimeLine

Events

Visual Navigation

Here all the items have same machine name except for Category Landing Page as it have machine name of "visual_navigation_landing" therefore when I click add content button on content page their I see the list as following

Alert

Article

Basic Page

TimeLine

Events

**Category Landing Page**

Visual Navigation

Here you can see "Category Landing Page" is at the bottom with visual navigation, can anyone help with this. I just want to sort this list by title and not machine name

Regards.

Comment: That's issue from core https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2693485. If you want to change order, you can apply patch or waiting version 8.7 realease.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to apply patch of "Content types are ordered by machine name on node/add"

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2693485

It resolved the issue